# Issue with Doctrine Criteria Matching

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

Using Doctrine 2, if I retrieve an entity by primary key and make a change to a field without flushing to the database, a subsequent criteria match will query the database for the association and incorrectly return the record with in memory changes. This record should be excluded, however because it hasn't been flushed the query still retrieves it.

Given this function:

```
public function getActiveUsers()
{
    $criteria = Criteria::create();
    $criteria->where(Criteria::expr()->eq('active', true));

    return $this->users->matching($criteria);
}
```

Running the following will output "true true"

```
foreach($organisation->getActiveUsers() as $user)
    echo ($user->isActive() ? 'true' : 'false');
```

However, marking one of those users as inactive and then running the same criteria match will output "false true" (should only output a single "true" as the first record should be excluded)

```
User::get(1)->setActive(false);

foreach($organisation->getActiveUsers() as $user)
    echo ($user->isActive() ? 'true' : 'false');
```

This bug is forcing me to perform a flush before every criteria query which is extremely draining on performance. If anyone can shed some light on this it would be appreciated

Comment: It is not a bug, it is a feature.  Queries are made against the database and not the in memory representations.  Doctrine 2 was designed for Request/Repsonse type applications where you make some changes, save the results and then start all over again.

Comment: Not sure how this could be a feature. If the association is hydrated before marking a record as inactive, the Criteria is applied on the in memory users, therefore excludes the record that was just marked as inactive. However, if the association has not been hydrated, the bug occurs.

Comment: The problem with your posted code is that you have some sort of active record wrapper going on.  Which is fine but I can't really tell exactly what your code is doing.  Consider writing a simple test case using "pure" Doctrine.  If it still gives unexpected results then file a bug report on the Doctrine github site.